# Pundit Scoping for Model Ownership through a Join table - Rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, pundit

I'm associating users with given firms through a join table because I need to be able to have a bunch of users with every firm and vice versa.

```
class User
  has_many :firm_connections, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :firms, through: :firm_connections
end

class FirmConnection
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :firm
end

class Firm
  has_many :firm_connections
  has_many :users, through: :firm_connections
end
```

My question is, when a user hits the index page for firms, how do I scope it to only show what those users are associated with?

```
class FirmPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      if user.admin?
        scope.all
      else
        scope.where #only the firms associated with that user
      end
    end
  end
```

Do I need to create a scope at the firm level that accepts a @user? Or can I do this all directly inline? I could hack something together, but haven't wrapped my head around pundit yet, so any direction would be greatly appreciated!

like this:

```
def self.associated_with(user)
  all.select { |m| m.users.include?(user) }
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you

```
class Firm
  def index
    @firms = policy_scope(Firm)
  end
end

class FirmPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      if user.admin?
        scope.all
      else
        user.firms #only the firms associated with that user
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The policy doesn't always have to call it the way that you think, it just has to return something (for scopes, almost always an ActiveRecord::Relation, for regular, true or false). You could do

```
scope.includes(:firm_connections).where(firm_connections: { user_id: user.id })
```

but that's not as readable (IMO).